# Generate thumbnail image on plugin

Tags: shopware6

how can I generate the thumbnail image for this section on the custom plugin?

```
{% for element in category.img.elements %}
   {% if element.media.url %}
      <img src="{{ element.media.url }}" class="product-image is-standard">
   {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

on this code it's only showing main image, I want to generate the thumbnail for that image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`sw_thumbnails` helper](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/use-media-thumbnails#working-with-sw_thumbnail).

```
{% for element in category.img.elements %}
    {% sw_thumbnails 'category-img-thumbnails' with {
        media: element.media,
        sizes: {
            'default': '200px'
        },
        attributes: {
            'class': 'some-class',
            'alt': 'alternative',
            'title': 'title'
        }
    } %}
{% endfor %}
```